# considering the middle numbers and edge numbers of N list to construct other lists

Tags: list-manipulation

We have `N=45` lists as below ones (I am bringing some of them to show their ordering)

```
list[1]={{0.26, 3, 0}, {0.26, 4, 0}, {0.26, 5, 0}, {0.26, 6, 0.0445602}};

list[2]={{0.27, 3, 0}, {0.27, 4, 0}, {0.27, 5, 0.129654}, {0.27, 6, 0}};

list[3]={{0.28, 3, 0}, {0.28, 4, 0.00488254}, {0.28, 5, 0.124178}, {0.28, 6, 
  0}};

.
.

list[20]={{0.45, 3, 0.228627}, {0.45, 4, 0}, {0.45, 5, 0}, {0.45, 6, 0}};

..

list[45]={{0.7, 3, 0.362271}, {0.7, 4, 0}, {0.7, 5, 0}, {0.7, 6, 0}};
```

If `n` is `3,4,5,...` (the middle value in each row of any list ) and considering two edge numbers of each row in any list we wish to reach:

```
extract[3]={{0.26,0},{0.27,0},{0.28,0}, .....,{0.7,0.36}};

extract[4]={{0.26,0},{0.27,0},{0.28,0.00488254}, .....,{0.7,0}};

extract[5]={{0.26,0},{0.27,0.129654},{0.28,0.124178}, .....,{0.7,0}};

extract[6]={{0.26,0.0445602},{0.27,0},{0.28,0}, .....,{0.7,0}};
```

and so on

By:

```
extract= {}; Do[AppendTo[extract, list[i]], {i, 1,45}];
```

we joined all of them. After that we do not know what should be done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here's one. Here are your lists:

```
list[1] = {{0.26, 3, 0}, {0.26, 4, 0}, {0.26, 5, 0}, {0.26, 6, 0.0445602}};
list[2] = {{0.27, 3, 0}, {0.27, 4, 0}, {0.27, 5, 0.129654}, {0.27, 6, 0}};
list[3] = {{0.28, 3, 0}, {0.28, 4, 0.00488254}, {0.28, 5, 0.124178}, {0.28, 6, 0}};
```

Then, define

```
Clear@extract
extract[n_] := extract[n] = Flatten[Join[Cases[list[#], {a_, n, b_} :> {a, b}] & /@ Range[3]], 1]
```

Then:

```
extract[1]
extract[3]
(* {} *)
(* {{0.26, 0}, {0.27, 0}, {0.28, 0}} *)
```

For your case, change `Range[3]]` to `Range[45]` if there are 45 such lists.

Comment: @Inzo. Yeah: that's what it does. `extract[1]` returns `{}` because there are no 3's. `extract[3]` returns `{{0.26, 0}, {0.27, 0}, {0.28, 0}}`, as it should.